# How can I run a command after every iteration of a command in a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a list of commands and run a certain command after each iteration:

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(5)
X = 960
Y = 556
move_to_list = [pyautogui.moveTo(X-300, Y),pyautogui.moveTo(X, Y-300),pyautogui.moveTo(X+300, Y),pyautogui.moveTo(X, Y+300),pyautogui.moveTo(X-300, Y)]
exit()
```

This is the code I have so far. I am trying to run `pyautogui.mouseDown()` after each command in the list.

I have tried making a for loop for each command in the list but I think I am doing it wrong. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: A hint: all those commands in `move_to_list` are being executed sequentially when the list is evaluated. You need to only call those functions inside a loop

Comment: As long as you have the round parentheses around the method name, the method will be executed right away. Even if you would iterate over the list (which you don't), it would be useless, because all the moveTo() methods have already been executed the time you inserted them into the list.

Comment: Do you need methods other than moveTo() in that list?

Answer (score 0):

Put all the coordinates in a list, then loop over that:

```
coords = [(X-300, Y), (X, Y-300), (X+300, Y), (X, Y+300)]
for x, y in coords:
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
    pyautogui.mouseDown()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually went back to coding after posting this post and did the exact same thing. It works!

Answer (score -2):

```
move_to_list = ['pyautogui.moveTo(X-300, Y)','pyautogui.moveTo(X, Y-300)','pyautogui.moveTo(X+300, Y)','pyautogui.moveTo(X, Y+300)','pyautogui.moveTo(X-300, Y)']
for x in move_to_list:
    print(x)
    print('yautogui.mouseDown()')
```

replace print with run command

Comment: Not sure on pyautogui . How do u run this commands . Generally we use os.system to run os commands like ls , cat etc

Comment: Do you mean [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)? If so, seems a bit of an over-complication for this scenario...

Comment: So, you actually don't know how to do it, but you expect this to be an answer for someone else?

Comment: What do you mean how to run this on pyautogui? This is just Python code. `os.system` is for executing system commands as if you run them in the terminal. Here you simply try to execute Python code from a string which is done with `eval` or [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)